# CRON Job? Wow this is over my head

Tags: cron, hosting, automatic-storage

I have no idea how to process cron jobs, however I can explain what I'd like it to do.... Anyone with experience on how to do this, would be very much appriciated....

1. Delete Oldest Files in a directory
2. Keep at least 8 of the newst files in a directory

Is it possible? I've been trying to understand documentation on this for a few hours, thought I would ask to save time in learning how to process these things... my host alows me to enter the cron jobs into the control panel backend.

I found this command

```
(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm
```

However, it dosent look like it knows which directory I want to delete from... and i have no idea what it does...

Comment: cron jobs allow you to execute commands or scripts at specific times. You should write a script which does what you want, and then just call that script regularly with a cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already wrote in my comment, the script which does what you want is independent of cron. 
Here is a possibility to do what you want:

```sh
cd /path/to/dir; ls -t | tail -n +9 | xargs rm
```

### Explanation

- `cd /path/to/dir`: goto directory
- `ls -t`: get a list of all files in the directory, sorted by last modification date, newest first
- `tail -n +9`: select all lines (in this case file names), starting with the 9th
- `xargs rm`: remove files which were 'selected' by previous commands

By selecting all lines beginning with the 9th, the 8 newest files never get deleted.

I assume that only files are stored in the folder, as the `rm` command will only remove those. To also remove folders and all of their contents, you will have to use `rm -r`.

To read a detailed description of a command (e.g. `cd`, `ls`, `tail`, `xargs`, `rm`) use `man <command>`